# Intercept when url changes before the page is completely loaded

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to catch the event when the url is changed inside my browser using selenium?

Here is my scenario:

1. I load my website *test.com*
2. After all the static files are loaded, when executing one of the js file, I am redirected (not sure how) to another page *redirect-one.test.com/blah*
3. My browser gets the url *redirect-one.test.com/blah* and gets a 307 response to go to *redirect-two.test.com/blahblah*
4. Here my browser receives a final 302 to go to *final.test.com/*

The page of *final.test.com/* is loaded and at the end of this, selenium enables me to search for elements and so on...

I'd like to be able to intercept (and time the moment it happens) each time I am redirected.

After that, I still need to do some other steps for which selenium is more suitable:

5. Enter my username and password
6. Test some functionnalities
7. Log out

Here a sample of how I tried to intercept the first redirect:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


def url_contains(url):
    def check_contains_url(driver):
        return (url in driver.current_url)
    return check_contains_url

driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)

driver.get("http://test.com/")

try:
    url = "redirect-one.test.com"
    first_redirect = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(url_contains(url))
    print("found first redirect")
finally:
    print("move on to the next redirect...."
```

Is this even possible using selenium?

I cannot change the behavior of the website and the reason it is built like this is because of an SSO mechanism I cannot bypass.

I realize I specified python but I am open to tools in other languages.

Comment: If you are only interested in the timing, and no content, then Selenium is definitely **not** the tool. Look into anything that can do REST - there has to be a python library, and there has to be tutorials for that library.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is not the tool for this. All the redirects that the browser encounters are handled by the browser in a way that Selenium does not allow you to check.

You can perform the checks using `urllib2`, or if you prefer a sane interface, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Comment: I think my initial question is not complete because this is just the first part of the script. After having timed the differents parts between the redirects, I need to automatically fill out a username/password form and do some other action on the browser side.

Comment: Besides, the first redirect is triggered by an ajax call

Comment: i am facing the same problem and is open to all the suggestions.